# Can I add an 1066 MHz RAM module to my Lenovo G550, which currently has one 800 MHz module installed?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

I have a Lenovo G550 laptop. It currently holds a Samsung 2 GB RAM, I wish to place a 4 GB RAM in the empty slot.

This is my current RAM specs:

```
*-memory
     description: System Memory
     physical id: d
     slot: System board or motherboard
     size: 2GiB
   *-bank:0
        description: SODIMM Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
        product: M471B5673FH0-CF8
        vendor: Samsung
        physical id: 0
        serial: 667EF48A
        slot: M1
        size: 2GiB
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
    *-bank:1
        description: SODIMM Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns) [empty]
        physical id: 1
        slot: M2
        clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
```

it says 800 MHz clock speed, and laptop specs show motherboard supports RAM upto 8 GB 1066 MHz, can I attach a Transcend 4 GB DDR3 1066 MHz or 1600 MHz RAM with the old RAM. Will it have any problems (voltage,different manufacturers etc)? Or should I just keep a 4 GB RAM and take away the 2 GB one?

[image: output of dmidecode --type=memory]
[image: 2]

Comment: Installing a second RAM stick with a higher speed rating is not a problem. It will just underclock to the speed of the slowest stick that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you are wasting the new RAM, in the sense that if you already have a module in place with a lower clock, then the higher one will also run at lower clock speed. Thus, you will lose any advantage in speed, though you will still have higher memory.

As such, as long as the system boots up, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel [Radial Apps' answer](https://superuser.com/a/1159833/53590), while technically largely correct, presents an unnecessarily pessimistic view of the subject.

First thing first: Yes, *in modern systems,* **you generally can mix memory with different timings** without any problems. If it works (boots) at all, it should work just fine. It's not necessarily ideal, but it won't break anything. Your laptop is [2009 vintage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_Essential_laptops#G550) and reportedly uses DDR3 RAM, so it's recent enough that this should work just fine. It's also old enough that it would be showing its age by now.

That said, the system *will* **clock down all RAM to the lowest common denominator.** So if you have one 800 MHz stick and one 1066 MHz stick, both will run at 800 MHz.

This means that **you won't get the maximum performance possible out of the upgrade.** However, depending on your workload, it's perfectly possible that you will still see a *significant* performance boost from the additional RAM.

**If you are hitting swap or running low on cache today, which frankly seems highly likely with only 2 GB of RAM and modern software, even with the downclocking, it's perfectly possible that the net result will be a significant performance boost,** even though you won't be getting 100% of the possible performance out of the new RAM stick.

After all, your system is *currently* running with 800 MHz RAM; installing more RAM that gets used at 800 MHz (rather than, say, 1066 MHz) will not make that situation any worse!

Judging by your DMI data, it looks like your system has a 2 GB module soldered to the motherboard, and physically supports a maximum of 4 GB. Thus, you could add another 2 GB module, but it's basically a shot in the dark whether the system will even accept an added 4 GB module (because that brings you over its reported 4 GB maximum), and even if it does, it's unlikely that you would be able to use the RAM above 4 GB regardless of whether you are running a 32-bit or 64-bit OS and software.

Just make sure to buy the proper type of RAM for your system. For example, ECC RAM may or may not actually *work*, but only if your motherboard and CPU are ECC-capable will you get any benefit from the ECC-ness of the RAM. In your case, the RAM you have is non-ECC, which is indicated for example by dmidecode's `Error Correction Type: None`. Compare this output snippet from `dmidecode --type=memory` from my system, which uses ECC RAM:

```
Handle 0x0026, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC <====
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

...
Handle 0x002E, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0026
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits <====
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
...
```

When purchasing ECC RAM, you also need to know whether your motherboard uses *buffered* or *unbuffered* ECC RAM. *Most* non-server motherboards that support ECC RAM want unbuffered ECC RAM, but either way, this is not a consideration in your particular case.

Comment: so if i buy a 1600 MHz(considering it may become of use in future) is not a bad idea either? and no voltage issues to look for?

Comment: @sofmonk As long as it's the correct physical form factor, connector **and type** (for example, DDR3L SODIMM non-ECC), I can't think of anything that would be a problem. Modern RAM autonegotiates operating voltage within the same physical form factor, and between form factors it won't fit in the slot anyway.

Comment: dmidecode --type=memory tells " maximum capacity 4 GB " , that means adding 4 GB + 2 GB isn't possible, right?

Comment: @sofmonk If it does so under `Physical Memory Array` then your interpretation may be correct. How many `Memory Device` does it show, and what does it show as `Number Of Devices` in the physical array? Note: You may want to edit to amend your question to include the dmidecode data.

Comment: @sofmonk Judging by your DMI data, it looks like the 2 GB you currently have is fixed (very likely soldered) to the motherboard, and the system supports a maximum of 4 GB physically. Thus you almost certainly could add a 2 GB stick, but it's a shot in the dark whether adding a 4 GB stick will work, and if it works, it's likely that you won't be seeing any benefit from the added RAM above 4 GB. The remainder of my answer still applies.

Comment: the 2 GB RAM is removable ( not soldered), the online specs said that Lenovo G550 could support maximum 8 GB but the output shows otherwise,( I have a 64 bit OS ,I could easily go above 4 GB), should I rely on online specs(and manual) or on the output? If I buy 4 GB RAM ( 2 +4 ) then what will happen ?